# drbd installation in Ubuntu 10.04

Tags: ubuntu-10.04, drbd

In the guide on drbd.org, it says that:

> To get DRBD, you need to enable the universe component for your preferred Ubuntu mirror in /etc/apt/sources.list

What does this mean? In my sources.list everything is already uncommented. Do I need to add another repository? Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply: look for the lines that say "universe" at the end, something like this:

```
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid universe
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid universe
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid-updates universe
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid-updates universe
```

They're enabled by default, so you should be fine to just run the install.